# How to create/edit multiple has many items in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Post and Attachment models. Post model has title, body attributes. Attachment has title, file attributes. Post has_many Attachments.

In a single form, I want users to be able to add/edit multiple attachments.

Right now I am doing it like this:

**Controller@edit:**

- Convert existing attachments of a Post to an array and merge it with old input

**Form View:**

- Loop through attachments and output fields

  - Field names would be in the form of `attachments[id][title]`
  - If the ID is from existing attachment, it will be an integer. If it is new, it will be a random number, less than 1 (`Math.random()` in Javascript)

**Controller@update:**

- Loop through `Input::get('attachments')`

  - If the key is integer, validate the attachment for updation (file not required, we can use existing) and update
  - Else it is new attachment, validate it for creation and store it in an array
  - If all are valid, create all of those attachments
  - If there is validation error, redirect back `withInput()` and `withErrors()`

However, on return, the errors are not properly associated with input fields. I assume that is because I am using arrays instead of objects. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In relation to laravel, I would probably create the attachment objects firsthand and then add the objects to the post. This is also explained in the documentation under [Inserting Related Models](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

```
$atachments = array(
    new Attachment(array('title' => 'Attachment #1.')),
    new Attachment(array('title' => 'Image Lol.')),
    new Attachment(array('title' => 'The answer is 42.'))
);

$post = Post::find(1);

$post->attachments()->saveMany($comments);
```

You should be able to update your comments in the same way (of course without instantiating a new Attachment object).

Comment: What about validations? When there are validation errors, I send them back, and I want both errors and the old input to be present. That is not happening.